# Why dropbox is reading 3GB of data every 20 minutes?

Tags: 16.04, dropbox

I'm using dropbox on a headless machine. The machine is monitored using zabbix and the disk usage recently increased.

Since a recent reboot (and update), every 20 minutes, dropbox reads 3Go of data, and that was not the case before.

- The machine was rebooted with a new kernel (update from 4.10.0-32-generic to 4.10.0-37-generic).
- dropbox has updated (himself) from 36.4.22 to 37.4.29, at almost the same date

Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on this dropbox forum [question](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Sharing-and-collaboration/Too-high-disk-activity/td-p/109863/page/3), linking to this dropbox [help page](https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/high-cpu-usage).

The problem for `dropbox` was related to file permissions, some files were not writable by the user using dropbox, and was fixed by doing this :

```
sudo chown "$USER" "$HOME"
sudo chown -R "$USER" ~/Dropbox ~/.dropbox
sudo chattr -R -i ~/Dropbox
sudo chmod -R u+rw ~/Dropbox ~/.dropbox
```

It seems that dropbox stops to use the inotify infrastructure once it founds one file with incorrect permissions !